# SFML View: setCenter vs move. It's driving me crazy

Tags: c++, sfml

I come again to ask for help, based on the post [SFML Views setCenter vs rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50034864/sfml-views-setcenter-vs-rotation).

It was to be something absurdly simple, but it's becoming a nightmare!

What I want is simple: **move a view to the upper left corner of the global window and rotate it, but the axis should be at 0,0** and not at the center of the view, like the default.

The problem is that "setCenter" moves the view and "move" changes the center of the view. That is, one cancels the other.

I read a lot, I asked a lot, but so far no one gave me the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation of the sf::View class (https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/graphics-view.php):

> "Unlike drawable entites such as sprites or shapes, whose positions
>   are defined by their top-left corner (and can be changed to any other
>   point),  views are always manipulated by their center -- this is
>   simply more convenient.  That's why the function to change the
>   position of a view is named setCenter, and not setPosition."

It states that a view's origin is at its center. So if you want to fit the view to the upper left corner just do it with:

```
view.setCenter(view.getWidth() / 2, view.getHeight() / 2);
```

If you would like to center the corner of the window in the center of the view just do:

```
view.setCenter(0,0);
```

Now if you rotate the view, it always rotates around its center, so position the view appropriately before rotating it.
Let me know if you have further questions and if it helped.

Does the following work for you?

```
// This should set the view to the upper left corner with a size of 500x300
view.reset(sf::FloatRect(250, 150, 500, 300)); 

// Now you can rotate the view around its center:
view.setRotation(90);

// Don't forget to apply the view.
window.setView(view);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately I received support from a SFML forum user and the solution is in post https://stackoverflow.com/a/50069393/5074998.